# Как происходит передача аргумента в колбэк?

Tags: javascript, функции, callback

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

function check(word){
return word.length > 6
}
const result = words.filter(check);
```

В объявлении функции "check" мы передаем ей параметр "word", а когда вызываем ее в качестве колбэка, мы ничего ей не передаем. Каким образом она понимает что нужно взять в качестве аргумента элемент массива на котором она вызвана?

Comment: Не «вызываем в качестве колбэка», а «передаём в качестве колбэка». Ввзывать её будет метод filter, и он знает что надо передавать в колбэк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myObject(arg) {
  this.obj = arg

  this.filter = function(callback) {
    const newArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.obj.length; i++)
 //           вот так и происходит
 //             |
 //                   |
 //                   V
      if (callback(this.obj[i])) newArray.push(this.obj[i])

    return newArray
  }
}

function check(word) {
  return word.length < 6
}

const words = new myObject(['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'])
const result = words.filter(check)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

В спецификации filter указано, что в callback, коим у вас является функция check автоматически передаются аргументы. Первый из которых и обязательный - element. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

В вашем случае element - это элемент массива words.
Метод filter сам вызывает этот callback с нужным аргументом.